# How to specify the rotation value of an object with Unity's Update function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to specify the object rotation value in Unity.

I don't want to rotate the object.

I wrote the following code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

    public class test_rotate : MonoBehaviour {

        int test_x = 10;

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start () {

        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () {
            this.transform.Rotate(test_x, 0, 0);
        }
    }
```

Then the object starts to rotate.

[image]

This is not what I wanted.

I just want to set the rotation value of the object to (10,0,0).

I also tried the following code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class test_rotate : MonoBehaviour {

    int test_x = 10;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        this.transform.Rotate(test_x, 0, 0);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    }
}
```

Then it worked as expected, but I want to do this with the Update function instead of the Start function.

What should I do?

Comment: Why do you want to do that in UPDATE (running every frame) if you only want to set it once ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`transform.Rotate()` rotates the object every time it is called.

What you want to do is to set the transform's rotation instead: `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(test_x, 0, 0);`